# Comparing percentages when the group sum is not 100

Tags: data-visualization, descriptive-statistics

Wondering if my method here for coding qualitative research data is valid.

My raw data looks like this:

|  | Contains apples | Contains bananas | Contains pears |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Cart 1 |  | x |  |
| Cart 2 | x |  |  |
| Cart 3 |  | x | x |
| Cart 4 | x | x |  |

I then added another column for shopping carts with more than 1 type of fruit:

|  | Contains apples | Contains bananas | Contains pears | More than 1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Cart 1 |  | x |  |  |
| Cart 2 | x |  |  |  |
| Cart 3 |  | x | x | x |
| Cart 4 | x | x |  | x |

Total of all carts,

|  | Contains apples | Contains bananas | Contains pears | More than 1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Total | 2 | 3 | 1 | 2 |

Expressed as a percentage, do I divide by 8 (the row sum) or by 4 (the number of carts)?
I've found that if I divide by 4 to get "X% of carts contained bananas", the row sum is not 100%, due to the 'More than 1' column. Dividing by the row sum gives me percentages which sum to 100, but I'm not totally sure what they mean.

Comment: You are discussing how to *code* variables, but you haven't yet explained *why.*  The answer depends on how you intend to use this coding for analysis and interpretation.  Please explain.

Comment: Why do you expect that your row sum should add to 100%?

Comment: I guess because, if I have percentages, I am expecting that the whole is represented in the data somehow. The fact that I can't find a whole when dividing by the number of carts in my example makes me question it.
What if the example I gave is only for customers on Monday, and I repeat this process for customers on Tuesday? I want to compare percentages for total of all carts between these days - which is correct? Divide by number of carts, or divide by row sum?